# 50% inline-blocks not displaying next to each other

Tags: html, css

Say I have

```
<span class="ib-half"></span>
<span class="ib-half"></span>
```

and

```
.ib-half {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I expect the two spans to display side-by-side but they won't. There's no margin, padding, or border, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The actual problem is the space (newline) between the two elements. Because it's an inline-block element, it registers the space, so it's 50% + the space.

Some possibilities:

```
<span class='left'>Left</span><!--
--><span class='right'>Right</span>
```

or `<span class='left'>Left</span><span class='right'>Right</span>`

or

```
<span class='left'>Left</span><span
class='right'>Right</span>
```

**or to me it really probably makes the most sense to** `float: left;` and change it to a `display: block` element. I believe the nature of inline elements is to operate in the same manner as text with some extra spacial information, so why get hacky when there's no reason to?

Answer (score 15):

Setting the **font-size** of the parent element to zero may be a fix.

HTML :

```
<div class = "parent">
    <span class="ib-half">Left</span>
    <span class="ib-half">Right</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
span{
    background:#bdbdbd;
}

.ib-half {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    font-size:10px;
}

.parent {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/YpTMh/9/

For more options please refer to http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Since inline-blocks are part of the inline flow it gets affected by spaces. Setting font-size:0 effectively makes that space 0 width.

Answer (score 5):

good answer in css3 is:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

in parent node, and :

```
white-space: normal;
vertical-align: top;
```

in div (or other) at 50%

exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/YpTMh/19/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
    <div>    
        <span class="ib-half"></span>
        <span class="ib-half"></span>
    </div>

​
       div{
           width:50%;
           display:block;
       }
       .ib-half {
           margin:0;
           display:inline-block;
           width: 49%;
           height:100px;
          }​
```

here i am using a parent div and setting its width and display property to block. In the child block u can set the display property to inline-block, and if u want more span to be added the u can add by decreasing the width of the span block 100/(no: of blocks) -1 .
You can also use float property to get the result.

Comment: since it is half, setting it to 49% does not make sense at all!