# CSS Float Clear Both 50 percent width Div with Border

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="leftInRow5050 squareTopLeft">1</div>
    <div class="rightInRow5050 squareTopRight">2</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="leftInRow5050 squareBottomLeft">3</div>
    <div class="rightInRow5050 squareBottomRight">4</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rightInRow5050{
    width:50%;
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
}

.leftInRow5050{
    width:50%;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.leftInRow5050.squareTopLeft{
    height: 35%;
        border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.rightInRow5050.squareTopRight{
    height: 35%;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.leftInRow5050.squareBottomLeft{
    height: 35%;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;  
}

.rightInRow5050.squareBottomRight{
    height: 35%;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;  
}
```

Why is the above code failing to create a 2X2 `<div>` matrix?
It is giving me the standard 1px problem, where the `<div>`'s fall under one another?

Comment: have you set a width for the parent div

Comment: I have not set any width for the parent div.
Why should the width be set for parent div?
I believe height is not an issue. Only width is the problem here.

Comment: you are constantly changing the code for your question. so just make up your mind about the code please

Comment: I am done with the changes, I had a problem formatting it. Now I am done.

Comment: Why you no create fiddle :(

Comment: ok I have created a fiddle for you (sigh) .http://jsfiddle.net/2jrQd/ . Now tell me what is wrong with this output

Comment: I'm looking at your fiddle in Chrome and it looks like a 2x2 to me. Exactly what problem are you having?

Comment: My mistake! The main problem is with border around the div. Let me update the code for one final time.
Donno how to transfer fiddle to SO. Please bear with me.

Comment: FYI, Floating elements don't obey display property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [50% inline-blocks not displaying next to each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831819/50-inline-blocks-not-displaying-next-to-each-other)

Comment: Well nows its because of your borders.... `50% + 50% = 100% + borders 1px = over 100%!!!` Its going to push it to the next line.

Comment: @Nit this post is different. it is about `float` not `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @Ruddy I understood that but how can I avoid that 1px?
I thought the div with clear:both will do it. But it did not.

Comment: This question has been answered...several times. Your original question was answered, and now that you've added borders to your example, that has been answered by **Ruddy**

Comment: @AdityaKappagantula What do you mean avoid it? Just dont place it. You cant have it over `100%`. You could change to `49%` or do this `margin-left: -2px` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/2jrQd/1/) Or `border-box` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/2jrQd/2/)

Comment: Simma dahn nah! This is supposed to be a helpful community. Just because @Ruddy can do math doesn't mean he understood the problem in the least.

Comment: @Frankenscarf But the fact is I **DO** understand the problem and even gave ways to fix it.

Comment: @Ruddy Though the solution sounds valid, I was against losing even a single pixel on my webpage. I guess, the tweak with box-sizing is what I was looking for.

Comment: @AdityaKappagantula I understand that, its just possible solutions. Glad you found one that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the div's have a border and that's what's throwing it off, try this:

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

Comment: perfect! It worked.
I would appreciate if you can throw more light on box-sizing.

Comment: @AdityaKappagantula [Learn about it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd183522(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Also remember this is a `CSS3` property!

Comment: yaa I am interested to serve only the latest browsers so I guess it won't be a problem.
Would welcome to know any potential threats that can emerge because of using this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width and float for the right divs. See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ycq5M/)

```
.leftInRow5050 {
    width:50%;
    float:left;

}
.rightInRow5050 {
    width:50%;
    float:right; /* or left */

}
```

Edited to add: the code example changed while I was answering :p