# Understanding CSS Box Layout Without Floats

Tags: css, layout

I read recently that floats are out and inline-block is the best way forward. I also learned about the box-sizing property.

I want to know why I have to reduce the width of the either of the first two boxes in the code below to make them sit next to each other. I thought that was exactly what the box-sizing property was meant to avoid?

Also, I'd love to know how to prevent the border between boxes 2 and 3 from doubling its width.

HTML:

```
<main>
    <section id="textInput">Input</section>
    <section id="display">Output</section>
    <section id="buttons">
        <button type="button" id="button1">Click me!</button>
    </section>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
#textInput {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;  
    padding: 2px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#display {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
}
#buttons {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the double border issue, just set `border-bottom:none;` on both `#textInput` and `#display` as follows, you can also use `border-right:none;` in the same manner for `#textInput`:

**EDIT**

You actually have Invisible ***spaces*** in your HTML (this is causing the issue), check the updated code, you do not need to reduce the width..

When using `box-sizing: border-box;`, the width is distributed as follows :

> **border width (left and right)** + **padding (left and right)** + **element
>   width (remaining)** = **width property set in CSS**

```css
main {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
#textInput {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;  
    padding: 2px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
   border-bottom:none;
   border-right:none;
}
#display {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-bottom:none;
    height: 100px;
}
#buttons {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
   
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section id="textInput">Input</section><section id="display">Output</section><section id="buttons">
        <button type="button" id="button1">Click me!</button>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm confused though - I'm using notepad++ and I've set it to display all characters. At the end of each line there is CRLF. I can't see any spaces. The code works when it's all on one line, but is hard to read and work with. How can I keep the HTML readable while avoiding this "invisible space" problem?

Comment: Check this out [stack issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831819/50-inline-blocks-not-displaying-next-to-each-other), another link [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). This is a common issue, the newline itself confuses the CSS.. Check the `font-size` solution in the stack answer, I think this is how you can avoid it and keep ut HTML readable.

Comment: Thanks again. It seems kind of complex - I thought the idea of using inline-block is that it's more semantic, but it looks like you either have to hack the HTML or add an extra container div with font-size 0, which is surely not semantic either. Seems like there is no advantage to abandoning floats given these drawbacks. Actually for my purposes, it could be that a table is most useful - some aligned regions of adjustable size for a very simple UI. I must say I'm finding learning CSS very frustrating!